# Need to find the position of @ in the result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column email address and the inputs are

```
email

abc@gmail.com
123ad@hotmail.com
```

and so on

I want to know at which position `@` is coming, like in `abc@gmail.com` it is coming in 4th position so in output it should print 4.

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag the question appropriately.

Comment: `CHARINDEX` for SQL Server.

Comment: `SELECT CHARINDEX('@', email, 1) FROM Tbl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you would use `charindex()` . . .

```
select charindex('@', email)
```

Other databases use functions such as `position()` and `instr()`.

Answer (score 0):

For your ms sql database:

```
SELECT email, CHARINDEX('@', email) 
FROM table_name;
```